# IOS custom pricing?

Tags: ios, customization

Are we restricted to the prices in the pricing tiers? E.g USD 1.99, 2.99, 3.99? I couldn't see anywhere to put in custom pricing.

Comment: I beg to differ that it's off-topic. It matters internally in my code where the pricing is defined. /YR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're restricted the Apple pricing matrix. See the link below to see how much of the proceeds go directly to you from the pricing tier you choose, and some other information regarding the different pricing tiers:

http://www.app-machine.com/hmcms_media/public/files/ApplePreis_Matrix.pdf

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I just remember a while back seeing prices that didn't end in 0.99 so wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something critical.